# Cassandra not working after upgrading to Finchley.RELEASE

Tags: cassandra, spring-cloud, spring-data-cassandra

PFB the error details.
Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/walgreens/coupons/config/CommonConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'session' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cluster' defined in class path resource [com/walgreens/coupons/config/CommonConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster

**build.gradle**

```
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.Dockerfile
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

buildscript {
ext
{ springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE' }



{{dependencies {
classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
classpath ("com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.2.1")
classpath ("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5")
classpath("au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-gradle_2.12:3.5.13")
classpath ("com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0")

}}}

}

plugins
{ //id "au.com.dius.pact" version "3.5.7" id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "1.4.17" id "de.undercouch.download" version "3.4.2" }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'au.com.dius.pact'
apply plugin: 'scala'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

ext
{ springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RELEASE' }

pact {
serviceProviders {
rxorder {
publish
{ pactDirectory = '/Users/sv/Documents/doccc/target/pacts' // defaults to $buildDir/pacts pactBrokerUrl = '[http://localhost:80|http://localhost/]' version=2.0 }

}
}
}

//start of integration tests changes
sourceSets {
integrationTest {
java
{ compileClasspath += main.output + test.output runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output srcDir file('test/functional-api/java') }

resources.srcDir file('test/functional-api/resources')
}
}

configurations
{ integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime }

//end of integration tests changes
dependencies {
//web (Tomcat, Logging, Rest)
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
// Redis
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
//Mongo Starter
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name:'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'



{{// Configuration processor - To Generate MetaData Files. The files are designed to let developers offer â€œcode completionâ€? as users are working with application.properties
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor'
// Actuator - Monitoring
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'

//Sleuth - Tracing
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
//Hystrix - Circuit Breaker
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix'
// Hystrix - Dashboard
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard'
// Thymeleaf
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
//Voltage
// Device Detection
//compile group: 'com.datastax.cassandra', name: 'cassandra-driver-core', version: '3.3.0'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra', version:'1.5.12.RELEASE'
compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0')
compile('org.json:json:20170516')

//Swagger
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version:'2.8.0'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version:'2.8.0'

//Lombok
compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok'
compile group: 'io.smartcat', name: 'cassandra-diagnostics-connector21', version: '1.4.10'
//Testing
//Spring WS Test
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-test', version:'2.4.0.RELEASE'

testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
{ exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module:"android-json" }

//Pact
testCompile group: 'au.com.dius', name: 'pact-jvm-provider-gradle_2.12', version: '3.5.7'
testCompile group: 'au.com.dius', name:'pact-jvm-provider-junit_2.12',version:'3.5.13'
testCompile group: 'au.com.dius', name:'pact-jvm-consumer-junit_2.12', version:'3.5.13'

//Embedded mongo for testing
testCompile group: 'de.flapdoodle.embed', name:'de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo',version:'2.0.1'
//testCompile group: 'cz.jirutka.spring', name: 'embedmongo-spring', version: '1.1'

compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-jvm', version: '1.2.5'
testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5'
testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '1.2.5'

testCompile('org.cassandraunit:cassandra-unit-spring:3.5.0.1')
{ exclude group: 'org.cassandraunit', module: 'cassandra-unit' }

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.cassandraunit/cassandra-unit-shaded
compile group: 'org.cassandraunit', name: 'cassandra-unit-shaded', version: '3.5.0.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hectorclient/hector-core
compile group: 'org.hectorclient', name: 'hector-core', version: '2.0-0'

integrationTestCompile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-test', version:'2.4.0.RELEASE' //changes for integration tests
integrationTestCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
{ //changes for integration tests exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module:"android-json" }

integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5' //changes for integration tests
integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '1.2.5' //changes for integration tests}}

}

dependencyManagement {
imports {
mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
}

}
```

Comment: Spring cloud has nothing to do with cassandra, did you also upgrade boot to 2.0.x? If so, there may be something there.

Comment: No i did not change anything except spring cloud version. I was already using spring boot 2.0.1 and i tried with 2.0.3 as well, but nothing is working.

Comment: Usually those kinds of errors are a corrupt maven or Gradle download. Nothing in spring cloud could cause this.

Comment: yes i agree, but not able to find any root cause of this issue. Same test cases working when we run individually, but it is not working when we run through gradle test.

Comment: So this is a Gradle issue? Your post is very light in details.

Comment: I have added my build.gradle file. Could you please look at it and let me know if you find any issues in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help. We were able to resolve the issue by adding the following dependencies separately.

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.2-jre'
compile group: 'org.apache.cassandra', name: 'cassandra-all', version: '3.11.3'
```